# What are the hidden achievements in Genshin Impact?

Tags: achievements, genshin-impact

Today I received a particularly interesting achievement by chance:

[image]

As far as I know, I had never seen this achievement in any of the achievement tabs.  The achievement tab this was listed in was "Wonders of the World", which I was monitoring as I was trying to finish all of them. As it turns out, there seems to be more hidden achievements that aren't listed in any of the tabs until you unlock said achievement.

That said -- what are these hidden achievements? How many are there, and what are their conditions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to the [Genshin Impact Wikia page for Hidden Achievements: Wonders of the World](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Achievements#Wonders_of_the_World) for a full and up-to-date list of all the hidden achievements currently in the game as of **1.2**

---

| Area | Name | Requirements |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mondstadt | The Remains of the Gale | Climb to the top of Stormterror's Lair |
| -- | Beloved of the Anemo Archon | Sit in the hands of the God Statue in Mondstadt |
| -- | Nothing To Lose But Time | Solve the sundial puzzle on the hidden island |
| -- | Get Your Own Emergency Food: | Consume the food during "Food Delivery" |
| Liyue | Scourge of the Battlefield | Sell the Nameless Treasures to someone |
| -- | Unswerving | Open the heart-shaped rock chest (requires at least 1 other co-op player) |
| N/A | Bon Appetit | Have all members of your party be fed to full |
| N/A | Boared to Death | Be defeated by a wild boar |
| N/A | Dolorous Stroke | Defeat an enemy by Shattering the ice they are trapped in |
| N/A | "If you put your heart into it..." | Cook one bad dish |
| N/A | "...anyone can be a gourmet" | Cook ten bad dishes |
| N/A | Golden Gliding License | Glide a "long distance" (Stormbearer Point > hidden island is the easiest way to get) |
| N/A | It's the Same as Having Wings | Glide for 80 seconds at once |
| N/A | Run, Melos! | Sprint continuously for over 15s. |
| N/A | Fantastic Four | Complete a domain in which all party members are all of the same element type. |